# Using C++11 smart pointers as C function arguments

Tags: c, pointers, c++11, smart-pointers

While this should be a trivial question I was unable to find an answer this far. In C APIs there are lots of functions that take pointers and pointers to pointers as arguments.
How can I use PROPERLY smart pointers as arguments with C APIs.

Here is an example that I'd like to convert to using std::unique_ptr:

```
FMOD_SYSTEM* system = nullptr;
result = FMOD_System_Create(&system); // Create the main system object

FMOD_SOUND* musicStream;
result = FMOD_System_CreateSound(system,
                                 musicStreamPath,
                                 FMOD_CREATESTREAM,
                                 nullptr,
                                 &musicStream);
```

Reference:
[FMOD_System_Create](http://www.fmod.org/docs/content/generated/FMOD_System_Create.html)
[FMOD_System_CreateSound](http://www.fmod.org/docs/content/generated/FMOD_System_CreateSound.html)

I start declaring the smart pointers as:

```
std::unique_ptr<FMOD_SYSTEM> system = nullptr;
std::unique_ptr<FMOD_SOUND> musicStream = nullptr;
```

Here are the compiler errors if I use .get():

> cannot convert 'std::unique_ptr::pointer {aka
>   FMOD_SOUND*}' to 'FMOD_SOUND**' for argument '5' to 'FMOD_RESULT
>   FMOD_System_CreateSound(FMOD_SYSTEM*, const char*, FMOD_MODE,
>   FMOD_CREATESOUNDEXINFO*, FMOD_SOUND**)'
>                                         musicStream.get());
>
> ```
>                                                    ^
> ```

Comment: Use the [`.get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get) method to get the underlying pointer?

Comment: Does not work with just .get(). There seems to be more to it but I cannot figure it out yet.

Comment: There's a real question and answer here. I'm working on it.

Comment: In any event, unless you are actually supposed to be calling `delete` on that pointer (pretty unlikely if it's returned by a C API), you have to supply a custom deleter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is because that C API expects you to pass it *the address of* a pointer to an `FMOD_SYSTEM`, so that the API can fill in that pointer with the result — i.e., it takes the `FMOD_SYSTEM*` as an *out-parameter*.

In C++, the idiomatic way to do that would be to pass *a reference to* a (smart?) pointer to an `FMOD_SYSTEM`, i.e., where the C API is

```
FMOD_RESULT FMOD_System_Create(FMOD_SYSTEM **system);

FMOD_SYSTEM *system;
result = FMOD_System_Create(&system);
```

the C++ API would be

```
FMOD_RESULT FMOD_System_Create(std::unique_ptr<FMOD_SYSTEM> &system);

std::unique_ptr<FMOD_SYSTEM> system;
result = FMOD_System_Create(system);
```

However, there's a big problem with this C++ API! The problem is that *creating* an `FMOD_SYSTEM` and *wrapping it in a `unique_ptr`* are separate concerns, and shouldn't be mashed together like this. For example, what if I'm doing something clever with threading and really need my `FMOD_SYSTEM` to be managed by a `shared_ptr` instead of simply a `unique_ptr`? I have to create a `unique_ptr` to pass as the out-parameter and then `std::move` it into a `shared_ptr` afterward? That's both ugly and (micro-)inefficient.

```
std::unique_ptr<FMOD_SYSTEM> fake_system;
result = FMOD_System_Create(fake_system);
std::shared_ptr<FMOD_SYSTEM> system(std::move(fake_system));
```

The answer is to recognize that the root of the problem is out-parameters themselves, and that the solution is *value semantics*. The idiomatic C++ syntax we *want* to write is

```
auto system = std::make_unique<fmod_system>();
```

and the way we obtain that syntax is by wrapping up the C API's raw pointers in value classes:

```
class fmod_system {
    FMOD_SYSTEM *ptr;
    fmod_system() {
        auto result = FMOD_System_Create(&ptr);
        if (result != FMOD_OK) {
            ptr = nullptr;
            throw something;
        }
    }
    fmod_system(fmod_system&&) = default;
    fmod_system& operator=(fmod_system&&) = default;
    fmod_system(const fmod_system&) = delete;
    fmod_system& operator=(const fmod_system&) = delete;
    ~fmod_system() {
        auto result = FMOD_System_Release(ptr);
        assert(result == FMOD_OK);  // destructors shouldn't throw: use your best judgment here
    }
};
```

And in fact at this point our callers can drop the `unique_ptr` obfuscation and simply write

```
fmod_system system;
```

unless they really *need* the extra layer of pointer semantics for some reason.

Comment: In that context. Is there a general rule of thumb how to use C APIs in a proper C++ style?

Comment: @Zingam: The hot phrase right now is "value semantics"; the older and almost synonymous phrase is "RAII". Googling both of those should turn up some good rules of thumb. If that doesn't help, I'd recommend posting another question — and make it as narrowly focused as possible. And/or, try writing the code yourself and then post it over on [CodeReview Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) for feedback!

Comment: While both terms are good search hints, value semantics and RAII are two mostly orthogonal concepts. Value semantics is about (simplified) to make your types behave like `ints` (in particular with respect to copy semantics). RAII is a technique to make sure ressources get automatically released

Comment: @MikeMB Absolutely correct; although then I went back and read my answer and I guess I still think "value semantics and RAII are [similar]" is true *in this particular context*. RAII is about writing good destructors; value semantics is about writing good special member functions in general; both are about how to avoid exposing `shared_ptr`/raw-pointer antics to the end-user the way Zingam was originally doing. (That is: *in this context* I'm gonna stick to my assertion that they're more "almost synonymous" than they are "mostly orthogonal". I think we both agree it's not 100% or 0%.)

Answer (score 3):

In general, I don't believe it is a good idea to mix C-APIs wiht smart pointers and the better approach is to wrap the C-API in a C++ Class as Quuxplusone suggested.

However, to answer your question, the "cleanest" (but still ugly way) I can think of is to pass the raw pointer to a smartpointer with a custom deleter, after the object has been created.

```
struct FMOD_SYSTEM_Deleter {    
    void operator()(FMOD_SYSTEM* sys) {
         if (sys !=  nullptr) {
             FMOD_System_Release(sys);
         }
    }
}

FMOD_SYSTEM* tsys = nullptr;
result = FMOD_System_Create(&tsys);
std::unique_ptr<FMOD_SYSTEM,FMOD_SYSTEM_Deleter> system(tsys);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer would be: C++ Smart Pointers are used for self allocated objects you would create with `new` and `delete`.
They are not build for pointers to objects witch are created internally by 3rd party C style API functions and need to be released by another C Style API function.
In your case you will have to call `System::release` and not `delete`, so using a smart pointer might cause big problems.

You have three possibilities:

1. Just stay with the C Style and take care of calling release yourself. (I would prefer this)
2. Write your own C++ wrapper class - like Quuxplusone suggested
3. Modify the C++ smart pointer with a custom "allocator" and
   "deleter" (This is complicated, theoretical and not recommended)

Comment: Nothing theoretical about using a c++ smpartpointer with a costum deleter (And arguably it is also not too complicated).